# How can I make terminal UIs accessible?

Tags: accessibility, command-line

I am looking for resources (software, studies, documentation) to help inform design decisions for making command line utilities accessible.

Most of the programs I work on are command-line utilities. Many are non-interactive, but the more complex ones are "TUIs" or terminal UIs.

These TUIs have features such as tabs, interactive navigation, progress bars, key bindings etc..

I am not familiar with adaptive software for terminals (is there an equivalent of a screenreader?) and therefore am not sure how these types of TUI features may impact users with vision or motor impairments.

Comment: Hi Nick, what do you mean about accessible? Most TUIs are quite accessible and customizable to improve accessibility (to some degree). Do you have any specific concern such as voice commands or are you talking in general?

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the following links if it helps:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/03/interactive-command-line-application-node-js/#chalk

https://pa11y.org/

https://zapier.com/engineering/how-to-cli/

Comment: You research brought valuable  references  Could you add some lines or description that explain each links essential contribution to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Accessibility of *CLI*s may be only achieved **on behalf of the terminal/shell environment** the *command-line application* is run on.

#### Accessible user interface

Since the nature of CLI brings **keyboard input** and (major only) **textual output** with it, they can be accessed by **screen/text readers** as *output-adapter* and **keyboard(-emulators**, e.g on-screen keyboard or voice-recognition) as *input-adapters*.

#### See the various platforms' features

- [Windows Terminal Preview v0.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-v0-3-release/) has new Accessibility features.
- [Linux Accessibility Site](http://linux-a11y.org/)